# Add click event to Ajax after it is finished loading to load more pages through pagination using Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

```
   <?php 
            //Get Current user and Home url
              global $current_user;
              get_currentuserinfo();
              $kd_bpuser = $current_user->user_login;
              $homeurl = get_home_url();
            ?>

            <script>
            //Pass home url and current user to javascript
              var bpUser = <?php echo json_encode($kd_bpuser); ?>;
              var bpUrl = <?php echo json_encode($homeurl); ?>;
              var bpFullUrl = bpUrl +"/members/" + bpUser + "/forums/subscriptions/"; 
              var bpData = "#bbp-author-unread-topics";

            </script>

            <div id="bbpress-forums">  

             <script type="text/javascript">

                //Pull in member subscriptions page unread forum topics
                jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {

                    $("#bbpress-forums").load(bpFullUrl + ' ' +  bpData, function() {

                        //Change Link href
                        $('.bbp-topic-permalink').each(function(i, obj) {

                            var url = $(this).next().attr('href');
                            $(this).attr('href', url);

                        });

                        $('.bbp-author-name').each(function(i, obj) {
                            function fixMemberPath(url) {
                              var shorten = url.replace("forums/subscriptions/", "");
                              return shorten;
                            }

                            var url = $(this).attr('href');
                            $(this).attr("href", fixMemberPath(url) );

                        });    

                        $('.bbp-author-avatar').each(function(i, obj) {
                            function fixMemberPath(url) {
                              var shorten = url.replace("forums/subscriptions/", "");
                              return shorten;
                            }

                            var url = $(this).attr('href');
                            $(this).attr("href", fixMemberPath(url) );
                        });

                           $('a.page-numbers').live('click', function(e) {
                              e.preventDefault();
                              console.log('clicked');
                              var pageNav = $(this).attr('href');
                              console.log(pageNav);
                              id = '#bbp-author-unread-topics';


                              $("#bbpress-forums").load(pageNav + ' ' + id, function() {

                              });

                        });

                    });  //end ajax call



                }); //end doc.ready

              </script>
```

What I'm trying to do is pull in some data using the ajax.load() method then after that is complete attach a click event handler using .on() method to pull in new data when one of the pagination buttons is clicked.

I am getting the ajax is loaded console message in the script but it is not loading the page. I can click it and it doesnt do anything and no errors are being shown in console. Any help would be appreciated:)

Comment: when you view the network tab in developer tools, do you see anything returned from the call? alternatively you can overload the callback function with 3 params to check the status and errors. http://api.jquery.com/load/#example-1

Comment: Yes actually its for some reason returning (2) GET requests for the same url and if I click again it doubles the request to (4) , I click again its (8) returned GET requests. It keeps doubling for some strange reason. I have tried using it with .live() method as suggested in another post but still no resolve. I see the GET request but the content isnt being replaced for some reason. Maybe I need to empty that #div first? I'm still pretty new to working with ajax calls so I'm still experimenting.

Comment: Also I am using the ajaxComplete() because I believe the ajax request has to be finished first before I can attach and click events to the new portion of the dom, is this correct?

Comment: What version of jquery are you using

Comment: Heres the url, I jst pushed my changes to the test server so you can check there.  The jQuery is 1.11.1, its wordpress/buddypress website. The url is: http://nwotest.northwestoverland.com/   You can create a quick free account with a fake email, no confirmation needed. You have to be a member though to see the members version of the homepage where I am pulling in the data.